# Sequence column based on another column (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, sequence

I have Spring Data - JPA application with this PostgreSQL table:

| id | object_id | document_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bdc8b35b | 1 | file1_for_obj_1 |
| ea4746ab | 2 | file1_for_obj_2 |
| cd4f235c | 1 | file2_for_obj_1 |
| 2d7d5af9 | 1 | file3_for_obj_1 |
| e85824021 | 2 | file2_for_obj_2 |

I need to add a column `number` which will be the sequence number and will take into account the value of `object_id` column. That is, the idea is the numbering of lines related to one or another `object_id`.

So the table should look like this:

| id | object_id | document_name | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bdc8b35b | 1 | file1_for_obj_1 | 1 |
| ea4746ab | 2 | file1_for_obj_2 | 1 |
| cd4f235c | 1 | file2_for_obj_1 | 2 |
| 2d7d5af9 | 1 | file3_for_obj_1 | 3 |
| e85824021 | 2 | file2_for_obj_2 | 2 |

My first idea was to create a sequence that would generate new values. For example, like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE _document_sequence
    MINVALUE 1
    START WITH 1000
    INCREMENT BY 1
```

But in this case, it will not take into account the values of the `object_id` column. That is, probably, the generation should be in java code. In addition, I need to make a migration that will put down the values of the new column `number` for the existing rows. But I don't know how to do it most effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you are wanting effectively nor efficiently. You would need to create a sequence for *each object id* (10K ids then 10K sequences) and there will be gaps in the sequences. Alternatively, you could use a `MAX()+1` approach, but that virtually guarantees an eventual duplicate.  The simplest way getting what you ask for by creating a `view` and generating the `number` within. (See [Demo](https://%20https://dbfiddle.uk/9cgK-IcW))

```
create view <view name> as
       select t.*
            , row_number() over(partition by object_id  
                                    order by document_name
                                ) as number
         from <table name> t;
```